# How to do a simple MongoDB find query on LoopbackJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I just want to know how to perform a simple findAll or findOne query on loopbackjs.

On a different question someone suggest to me do do something like this:

```
module.exports = function(Transaction) {
    Transaction.observe('access', function(ctx, next) {
      Transaction.find({}, function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
      next();// be sure to call the callback function
      });
    });
};
```

But trying this on API explorer gives me an out of range error and also seems too complicated for a simple query.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. LoopBack is a REST API framework. If you simply hit `http://localhost:3000/api/Transactions` from your browser then you will execute a `find()` on your DB and get all records. What you have above is trying to do a `find()` any time a record is accessed, which results in an infinite loop. So... **What are you trying to do?**

Comment: Yes but what if I need to make my own APIs with custom logic? 
Maybe I will need to make a find query first, then process the data to return something different.

Answer (score 0):

Solver, just check docs here:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extend+your+API